# Sorting file contents numerically by field

Tags: bash, sorting

I am trying to write a BASH script to sort the contents of a file numerically according to a specific field in the file.

The file is under `/etc/group`. All of the fields are colon-separated `:`. I have to sort the contents of `/etc/group` numerically based on the 3rd field.

Example field: `daemon:*:1:root`

What I'm trying so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
sort /etc/group -n | cut -f 3-3 -d ":" /etc/group
```

This is getting me really close, but it only prints out a sorted list of 3rd field values (since `cut` literally cuts out the rest of the line). I'm trying to keep the rest of the line but still have it sorted by the 3rd field contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sort -t` like this:

```
sort -t : -nk3 /etc/group
```

`-t :` tells `sort` to use field delimiter as `:`

`-nk3` tells `sort` to sort data numerically on field #3